# Не работают клавиши клавиатуры в игре змейка на python(pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import time 

class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        # задаём размеры экрана
        self.screen_width = 720
        self.screen_height = 460

        # необходимые цвета
        self.red = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0)
        self.green = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)
        self.black = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
        self.white = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)
        self.brown = pygame.Color(165, 42, 42)

        # Frame per second controller
        # задаём кол-во кадров в секунду
        self.fps_controller = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.score = 0 # сколько еду сьели

    def init_and_check_for_errors(self):
        '''начальная функция для инициализации и проверки,
           как запуститься pygame'''
        check_errors = pygame.init()
        if check_errors[1] > 0:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print('OK')
            
    def set_surface_and_title(self):
        '''задаём surface(поверхность поверх котрой будет всё рисоваться) и устанавливаем 
        заголовок окна'''
        self.play_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((
            self.screen_width, self.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game')

    def event_loop(self, change_to):
        '''функция для отслеживания нажатий клавиш игрком'''

        # запускаем цикл по ивентам
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # если нажали клавишу
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    change_to = 'RIGHT'
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    event.key = 'LEFT'
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    event.key = 'UP'
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    event.key = 'DOWN'

                # нажали escape
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

        return change_to
                

    def refresh_screen(self):
        '''обновляем экрна и задаём фпс'''
        pygame.display.flip()
        game.fps_controller.tick(23) 

    def show_score(self, choice = 1):
        '''отображение результата'''
        s_font = pygame.font.SysFont('monaco', 24)
        s_surf = s_font.render(
            'Score {0}'.format(self.score), True, self.black)
        s_rect = s_surf.get_rect()

        # дефолтный случай отображаем результат слева сверху
        if choice == 1:
            s_rect.midtop = (80, 10)

        # при gameovere отображаем рузультат по центру, под надписью gameover
        else:
            s_rect.midtop = (360, 120)

        # рисуем прямоугольник поверх surface
        self.play_surface.blit(s_surf, s_rect)

    def game_over(self):
        '''функция для вывода ндписи game over и результатов в случае завершения игры или выхода из неё'''
        go_font = pygame.font.SysFont('monaco', 72)
        go_surf = go_font.render('Game Over', True, self.red)
        go_rect = go_surf.get_rect()
        go_rect.midtop = (360, 15)
        self.play_surface.blit(go_surf, go_rect)
        self.show_score(0)
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(3)
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()


class Snake():
    def __init__(self, snake_color):
        # важные переменные, позиция головы змеи и его тела
        self.snake_head_pos = [100,50] # [x,y]

        # начальное тело змеи состоит из трёх сегментов
        # голова змеи - первый элемент, хвост - последний
        self.snake_body = [[100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
        self.snake_color = snake_color

        # направление движения змени изначально зададим вправо
        self.direction = 'RIGHT'

        # куда будет меняться направление движении змеии при нажатии определённых клавиш
        self.change_to = self.direction


    def validate_direction_and_change(self):
        '''изменяем нпаравление движения змеи тольок в том случаем, если оно не прямо 
        противоположно текущему'''
        if any((self.change_to == 'RIGHT' and not self.direction == 'LEFT',
               self.change_to == 'LEFT' and not self.direction == 'RIGHT', 
               self.change_to == 'UP' and not self.direction == 'DOWN', 
               self.change_to == 'DOWN' and not self.direction == 'UP')):
            self.direction = self.change_to

    def change_head_position(self):
        '''изменяем положение головы змеи'''
        if self.direction == 'RIGHT':
            self.snake_head_pos[0] += 10
        elif self.direction == 'LEFT':
            self.snake_head_pos[0] -= 10
        elif self.direction == 'UP':
            self.snake_head_pos[1] -= 10
        elif self.direction == 'DOWN':
            self.snake_head_pos[1] += 10

    def snake_body_mechanism(self, score, food_pos, screen_width, screen_height):
        # если вставлять просто snake_head_pos
        # то навсех трёх позициях в snake_body 
        # окажетсья один и тот же список с одинаковыми коардинатами
        # и мы будем управять змеёй из одного квадрата 
        self.snake_body.insert(0, list(self.snake_head_pos))

        # если сьели еду
        if (self.snake_head_pos[0] == food_pos[0] and self.snake_head_pos[1] == food_pos[1]):
            # если сьели еду, то задаём новое положение еды случайным образом 
            # и увеличиваем score на один
            food_pos = [random.randrange(1, screen_width / 10) * 10, 
                        random.randrange(1, screen_height / 10) * 10]

            score += 1

        else:
            # если не нашли еду, то то убираем последний сегмент,
            # если этого не сделать, то змея будет постоянно расти
            self.snake_body.pop()

        return score, food_pos

    def draw_snake(self, play_surface, surface_color):
        '''отображаем все сегменты змеи'''
        play_surface.fill(surface_color)

        for pos in self.snake_body:
            # pygame.Rect(x,y, sizex, sizey)
            pygame.draw.rect(
                play_surface, self.snake_color, pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 10, 10))

    def check_for_boundaries(self, game_over, screen_width, screen_height):
        '''проверка, что столкнулись с концами экрана или сами с собой, 
        (змея закольцевалась)'''
        if any((
            self.snake_head_pos[0] > screen_width-10
            or self.snake_head_pos[0] < 0, 
            self.snake_head_pos[1] > screen_height-10
            or self.snake_head_pos[1] < 0
                )):                                               

            game_over() 

            for block in self.snake_body[1:]:
                # проверка на то, что первый элемент(голова) врезался в 
                # любой другой элемент змеи (закольцевалась)
                if (block[0] == self.snake_head_pos[0] and 
                        block[1] == self.snake_head_pos[1]):
                    game_over()


class Food():
    def __init__(self, food_color, screen_width, screen_height):
        '''Инит еды'''
        self.food_color = food_color
        self.food_size_x = 10
        self.food_size_y = 10
        self.food_pos = [random.randrange(1, screen_width / 10) * 10, 
                        random.randrange(1, screen_height / 10) * 10]

    def draw_food(self, play_surface):
        '''отображение еды'''
        pygame.draw.rect(play_surface, self.food_color, pygame.Rect(
            self.food_pos[0], self.food_pos[1], self.food_size_x, self.food_size_y))
        # Rect(поверхноссть, цвет и обьект)

game = Game()
snake = Snake(game.green)
food = Food(game.brown, game.screen_width, game.screen_height)

game.init_and_check_for_errors()
game.set_surface_and_title()


while True:
    snake_change_to = game.event_loop(snake.change_to)

    snake.validate_direction_and_change()
    snake.change_head_position()

    game.score, food.food_pos = snake.snake_body_mechanism(game.score, 
        food.food_pos, game.screen_width, game.screen_height)

    snake.draw_snake(game.play_surface, game.white)

    food.draw_food(game.play_surface)

    snake.check_for_boundaries(game.game_over, game.screen_width, game.screen_height)

    game.show_score()
    game.refresh_screen()
```

Код ошибок не каких не выдаёт, но клавиатура, то есть клавиши не работают.

Я не могу понять в чём проблема, ибо перерыл весь интернет и не нашёл ничего что мне было нужно. Я думаю что проблема в функции event_loop()
Кто знает пожалуйста помогите.

Answer (score 1):

Я решил вашу проблему:

1. Проблема в функции `event loop`.
   В первом условии вы все правильно написали `change_to = 'RIGHT'`, но в последующих что-то пошло не так и вы присваивали не той переменной и вообще не тому объекту, например `event.key = 'LEFT'`.
   Вот исправленная функция

```
def event_loop(self, change_to):
    '''функция для отслеживания нажатий клавиш игрком'''

    # запускаем цикл по ивентам
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # если нажали клавишу
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                change_to = 'RIGHT'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                change_to = 'LEFT'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                change_to = 'UP'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                change_to = 'DOWN'

             # нажали escape
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    return change_to
```

2. Также есть проблемка в цикле `while True:`.
   `snake_change_to = game.event_loop(snake.change_to)`. Вы присваивали значение в `snake_change_to`, а надо в `snake.change_to`
   Вот исправленный цикл

```
while True:
    snake.change_to = game.event_loop(snake.change_to)

    snake.validate_direction_and_change()
    snake.change_head_position()

    game.score, food.food_pos = snake.snake_body_mechanism(game.score,
                                                           food.food_pos, game.screen_width, game.screen_height)

    snake.draw_snake(game.play_surface, game.white)

    food.draw_food(game.play_surface)

    snake.check_for_boundaries(game.game_over, game.screen_width, game.screen_height)

    game.show_score()
    game.refresh_screen()
```

В итоге мы поучаем вполне работающий код:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import time


class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        # задаём размеры экрана
        self.screen_width = 720
        self.screen_height = 460

        # необходимые цвета
        self.red = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0)
        self.green = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)
        self.black = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
        self.white = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)
        self.brown = pygame.Color(165, 42, 42)

        # Frame per second controller
        # задаём кол-во кадров в секунду
        self.fps_controller = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.score = 0  # сколько еду сьели

    def init_and_check_for_errors(self):
        '''начальная функция для инициализации и проверки,
           как запуститься pygame'''
        check_errors = pygame.init()
        if check_errors[1] > 0:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print('OK')

    def set_surface_and_title(self):
        '''задаём surface(поверхность поверх котрой будет всё рисоваться) и устанавливаем
        заголовок окна'''
        self.play_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((
            self.screen_width, self.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game')

    def event_loop(self, change_to):
        '''функция для отслеживания нажатий клавиш игрком'''

        # запускаем цикл по ивентам
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # если нажали клавишу
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    change_to = 'RIGHT'
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    change_to = 'LEFT'
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    change_to = 'UP'
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    change_to = 'DOWN'

                # нажали escape
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

        return change_to

    def refresh_screen(self):
        '''обновляем экрна и задаём фпс'''
        pygame.display.flip()
        game.fps_controller.tick(23)

    def show_score(self, choice=1):
        '''отображение результата'''
        s_font = pygame.font.SysFont('monaco', 24)
        s_surf = s_font.render(
            'Score {0}'.format(self.score), True, self.black)
        s_rect = s_surf.get_rect()

        # дефолтный случай отображаем результат слева сверху
        if choice == 1:
            s_rect.midtop = (80, 10)

        # при gameovere отображаем рузультат по центру, под надписью gameover
        else:
            s_rect.midtop = (360, 120)

        # рисуем прямоугольник поверх surface
        self.play_surface.blit(s_surf, s_rect)

    def game_over(self):
        '''функция для вывода ндписи game over и результатов в случае завершения игры или выхода из неё'''
        go_font = pygame.font.SysFont('monaco', 72)
        go_surf = go_font.render('Game Over', True, self.red)
        go_rect = go_surf.get_rect()
        go_rect.midtop = (360, 15)
        self.play_surface.blit(go_surf, go_rect)
        self.show_score(0)
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(3)
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()


class Snake():
    def __init__(self, snake_color):
        # важные переменные, позиция головы змеи и его тела
        self.snake_head_pos = [100, 50]  # [x,y]

        # начальное тело змеи состоит из трёх сегментов
        # голова змеи - первый элемент, хвост - последний
        self.snake_body = [[100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
        self.snake_color = snake_color

        # направление движения змени изначально зададим вправо
        self.direction = 'RIGHT'

        # куда будет меняться направление движении змеии при нажатии определённых клавиш
        self.change_to = self.direction

    def validate_direction_and_change(self):
        '''изменяем нпаравление движения змеи тольок в том случаем, если оно не прямо
        противоположно текущему'''
        if any((self.change_to == 'RIGHT' and not self.direction == 'LEFT',
                self.change_to == 'LEFT' and not self.direction == 'RIGHT',
                self.change_to == 'UP' and not self.direction == 'DOWN',
                self.change_to == 'DOWN' and not self.direction == 'UP')):
            self.direction = self.change_to

    def change_head_position(self):
        '''изменяем положение головы змеи'''
        if self.direction == 'RIGHT':
            self.snake_head_pos[0] += 10
        elif self.direction == 'LEFT':
            self.snake_head_pos[0] -= 10
        elif self.direction == 'UP':
            self.snake_head_pos[1] -= 10
        elif self.direction == 'DOWN':
            self.snake_head_pos[1] += 10

    def snake_body_mechanism(self, score, food_pos, screen_width, screen_height):
        # если вставлять просто snake_head_pos
        # то навсех трёх позициях в snake_body
        # окажетсья один и тот же список с одинаковыми коардинатами
        # и мы будем управять змеёй из одного квадрата
        self.snake_body.insert(0, list(self.snake_head_pos))

        # если сьели еду
        if (self.snake_head_pos[0] == food_pos[0] and self.snake_head_pos[1] == food_pos[1]):
            # если сьели еду, то задаём новое положение еды случайным образом
            # и увеличиваем score на один
            food_pos = [random.randrange(1, screen_width / 10) * 10,
                        random.randrange(1, screen_height / 10) * 10]

            score += 1

        else:
            # если не нашли еду, то то убираем последний сегмент,
            # если этого не сделать, то змея будет постоянно расти
            self.snake_body.pop()

        return score, food_pos

    def draw_snake(self, play_surface, surface_color):
        '''отображаем все сегменты змеи'''
        play_surface.fill(surface_color)

        for pos in self.snake_body:
            # pygame.Rect(x,y, sizex, sizey)
            pygame.draw.rect(
                play_surface, self.snake_color, pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 10, 10))

    def check_for_boundaries(self, game_over, screen_width, screen_height):
        '''проверка, что столкнулись с концами экрана или сами с собой,
        (змея закольцевалась)'''
        if any((
                self.snake_head_pos[0] > screen_width - 10
                or self.snake_head_pos[0] < 0,
                self.snake_head_pos[1] > screen_height - 10
                or self.snake_head_pos[1] < 0
        )):

            game_over()

            for block in self.snake_body[1:]:
                # проверка на то, что первый элемент(голова) врезался в
                # любой другой элемент змеи (закольцевалась)
                if (block[0] == self.snake_head_pos[0] and
                        block[1] == self.snake_head_pos[1]):
                    game_over()


class Food():
    def __init__(self, food_color, screen_width, screen_height):
        '''Инит еды'''
        self.food_color = food_color
        self.food_size_x = 10
        self.food_size_y = 10
        self.food_pos = [random.randrange(1, screen_width / 10) * 10,
                         random.randrange(1, screen_height / 10) * 10]

    def draw_food(self, play_surface):
        '''отображение еды'''
        pygame.draw.rect(play_surface, self.food_color, pygame.Rect(
            self.food_pos[0], self.food_pos[1], self.food_size_x, self.food_size_y))
        # Rect(поверхноссть, цвет и обьект)


game = Game()
snake = Snake(game.green)
food = Food(game.brown, game.screen_width, game.screen_height)

game.init_and_check_for_errors()
game.set_surface_and_title()

while True:

    snake.change_to = game.event_loop(snake.change_to)

    snake.validate_direction_and_change()
    snake.change_head_position()

    game.score, food.food_pos = snake.snake_body_mechanism(game.score,
                                                           food.food_pos, game.screen_width, game.screen_height)

    snake.draw_snake(game.play_surface, game.white)

    food.draw_food(game.play_surface)

    snake.check_for_boundaries(game.game_over, game.screen_width, game.screen_height)

    game.show_score()
    game.refresh_screen()
```